# What should i do more to make it display the variables instead of the values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord.js

What  should i do more to make it display the variables instead of the values ?

i want to find the variable that has the lowest value which then would be entering a switch statement with the variables as the cases.

This is just an example with constant numbers. when the actual program runs, the numbers would keep changing. That's why i put it that way.

```
let x = 5,y = 7,z = 1;
let ima = [x,y,z];
let tiber = ima.sort((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(tiber);
```

Comment: Why do you want to create a variable for every element in the array?

Comment: i want to use .sort((a, b) => a - b) to make sure the first slot of the array has the least number. i want it so i can use switch(tiber[0]). i thought i can use this method but i guess not ?

Comment: Do you need to know which variable has the lowest value or just the value itself?

Comment: i need to know which variable has the lowest value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haki, try this:

```js
    y = 7,
    z = 1;
    x = 5;

    let ima = [{"name":"x", "value": x}, {"name":"y", "value": y}, {"name":"z", "value": z}];
    let tiber = ima.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);
    console.log(tiber[0].name + ": " + tiber[0].value);
```

Comment: Ah yes! It works! But, because of i only want the variable, so i do this ..

let ima = [{"name":"x", "value": x}, {"name":"y", "value": y}, {"name":"z", "value": z}];
let tiber = ima.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);
console.log(tiber[0].name);

But still, thanks to you my understanding about this array thing is improving! I hope my actual program would run well with this! Thank you!

Comment: tiber[0].name will be the variable name

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested arrays to represent each variable with its value or objects, to know which array/object contains the lowest value:

```js
let ima = [['x', 5], ['y', 7], ['z', 1]];
let tiber = ima.sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]);
console.log(tiber[0][0]);
```

or:

```js
let ima = [{name: 'x', value: '5'}, {name: 'y', value: '7'}, {name: 'z', value: '1'}];
let tiber = ima.sort((a, b) => a.value - b.value);
console.log(tiber[0].name);
```